# Rename directories from abc.folder.xyz to folder.xyz

Tags: linux, bash, command-line-interface, rename, mv

Say I have a directory with a bunch of site names in it.

i.e.

```
dev.domain.com
dev.domain2.com
dev.domain3.com
```

How can I rename those to `<domain>.com` on the linux cli using piping and/or redirection bash?

I get to a point than am stuck.

```
find . -maxdepth 1 | grep -v "all" | cut --delimiter="." -f3 | awk '{ print $0 }'
```

Gives me the domain part, but I can't get past that.  Not sure awk is the answer either.  Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: What would you like to rename to `.com`? Not all the files, right?

Comment: Just the directory names.  There are only directories within this directory and no files, so the answer shouldn't need to take the inode type into account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for i in *; do mv $i $( echo $i | sed 's/\([^\.]*\).\([^\.]*\).\([^\.]*\)/\2.\1/' ); done
```

Explained:

```
for i in *; do ....; done
```

do it for every file

```
echo $i | sed 's/\([^\.]*\).\([^\.]*\).\([^\.]*\)/\2.\1/'
```

takes three groups of "every character except ." and changes their order
\2.\1 means: print second group, a dot, first group

the **$( ... )** takes output of sed and "pastes" it after **mv $i** and is called "command substitution" http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Substitution

Comment: this answer was written before Spechal edited his question http://stackoverflow.com/users/427387/spechal

Comment: for i in *; do mv $i $( echo $i | sed 's/\([^\.]*\).\([^\.]*\).\([^\.]*\)/\2.\3/' ); done

Answer (score 2):

To strip the leading `'dev.'` from names it should be like this:

```
for i in $(find * -maxdepth 1 -type d); do mv $i $(echo $i | sed 's/dev.\(.*\)/\1/'); done
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the [rename](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rename) command. It can take a regular expression like this:

```
rename 's/\.domain.*/.com/' *.com
```

Comment: rename is not portable across all versions of linux

Comment: what are the problematic versions?

Comment: IIRC it's mostly older ones. Rename is newer, and not part of the 'standard' toolkit, partly because it's just a perl script. Watch out for slimmed down builds, like netbook or embedded builds, and for older debian builds.

Answer (score 0):

under the directory you want to work with, try :

```
ls -dF *|grep "/$"|awk  'BEGIN{FS=OFS="."} {print "mv "$0" "$2,$3}'
```

will print mv command. if you want to do the rename, add `"|sh"` and the end:

```
 ls -dF *|grep "/$"|awk  'BEGIN{FS=OFS="."} {print "mv "$0" "$2,$3}'|sh
```